# jqGrid set variable based on checkbox

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that looks like this:

```
      $(function(){
            $("#poGrid").jqGrid({
                url:'URL',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames:[],
                pager: '#poPager',
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                sortname: 'orderID',
                sortorder: 'ASC',
                jsonReader : { repeatitems: false },
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                caption: '&nbsp;',
                height: "100%",

                colModel :[

                    {name: 'sel', index: 'sel', label: 'Select', width:50, align: 'center',
                        editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"},
                        formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}},
                    {name:'orderID', label:'Order ID', width:80, align: 'center'},
                    {name:'orderName', label:'Order Name', width:250},
                    {name:'orderDate', label:'Order Date', width:100}


                ],


            });
        });
```

When the user clicks the sel checkbox I need to take the orderID and put it into a JS variable that is a comma separated string of orderIDs for the rows that the sel is checked.

I also need it to remove the orderID from the string when the checkbox is unchecked. I've been planning with using the onLoad event but I cannot get the syntax right.

Also, I save the orderID from the selected checkboxes in a DB. When the user reloads the page I can build the variable as comma separated string. I need to then make sure all the checkboxes load checked if the orderID is in that variable.

I hope this all makes sense and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can start by checking out:
[JQgrid checkbox onclick update database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208412/jqgrid-checkbox-onclick-update-database)

which will cover off your click events on your checkboxes. From that event you can build your string and remove the orderId's from the var that have been unselected.

If you save the data for which orderId's are checked then you can pass them down as 1/0's for your checkbox column and use a formatter: checkbox specified by Oleg's answer in 
[Add checkboxes in a jqGrid on the basis of value retrieved through the json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534521/add-checkboxes-in-a-jqgrid-on-the-basis-of-value-retrieved-through-the-json)

If you are dealing with multiple pages of data be sure to save your data back to the server before the page change as well.

If you want to build the variable server side you can always pass that down as userData as well. Ex

ServerSide

```
"userdata": { checkedOrderIds: "1,2,5,7"}
```

Client Side

```
var myUserData = jQuery("grid_id").getGridParam('userData');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, phpGrid has an conditional cell value example through server side script:

http://phpgrid.com/example/conditional-value/